# .hide only the current class, passing it by function JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, hide

I have a father class named 'report-desc', generated automatically with a foreach loop, with their 'Ignore' buttons.

The structure of each 'report-desc' is identical. I want to create an onclick event for 'Ignore' buttons with .hide effect but only to the current 'report-desc'. Now, this button is hiding all 'report-desc' classes.

Regards.

Comment: HTML Please & Show What you tired..

Comment: If your asking for code help, then some actual code would help...

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
 $('.ignore').on('click', function(){
     $(this).parents('.report-desc').addClass('hide');
 });
```

Comment: This would fire when any click is registered within the `report-desc` function - he could have anchors, etc

Comment: Ugh, I tried to undo the downvote but now it gave you an upvote. Not quite what I wanted. Oh well, solution works although he'll have to have an actual `.hide` css class

Comment: No problem. In the question he mentions the use of `.hide`

Comment: I interpreted that as the jQuery `.hide`, either way it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Some fashion of `.parent`. If it's not the direct child:

```
$('.ignore').click(function(){
  $(this).parents('.report-desc').hide();
});
```

Comment: What have i to send by function? this or nothing?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You essentially want an ignore button to only hide to the `report-desc` div it's inside of. This will do that

Comment: Ya but I have multiples report-desc divs, i want to hide only the current.

Comment: This does that. It only finds the direct parent of the currently clicked `ignore` button